# Piece of paper that was given to the main actor in Yesterday?

Tags: plot-explanation, yesterday

In the movie Yesterday, there's this guy who finds out that nobody knows about Beatles music and starts to sing the Beatles songs and gets famous. However, two other people along with him know about the Beatles.

Mid-movie, after one of his concerts, they approach him backstage to question him, In this scene, the lady hands him a piece of paper.

What is the significance of this paper? Are those lyrics to a song or some advice or something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yesterday_(2019_film))

> Jack persuades his label to launch the album with a performance in Gorleston. Backstage, Jack is approached by two Beatles fans who tell him they know he plagiarised the songs; however, they thank him, fearing the music of the Beatles had gone forever.

Avast spoiler!

> **They give him the address of Beatle John Lennon, who has lived into old age.**

Comment: Oh okay, I thought they gave him the lyrics to 'Eleanor Rigby' Because Jack had a tough time with the lyrics and was visiting places in Liverpool to complete the song.